# How would I expand my card at run time when user hits plus sign?

Tags: android

I have three cards in my view. One of the card is a comment section for me. where i have a plus sign in right hand top. What i want is that when a user hits plus sign height of that card expands and I see edit text so that user can type in his/her comment.I am new to android programming. Please suggest a way.

Comment: Use this one http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 0):

You can either change visibility of your comment section layout/component (see View.GONE and View.VISIBLE) or dynamically add required UI components when user hits an expand button.